# CSS Change cursor to hand on hover on a blur window

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two windows, one blur(say A) and the other one(say B) in focus.

On the blur window(A) there are several  tags. Keeping the other window (B) in focus, how can I change the cursor to hand if I hover over the anchor tag in the blur window (A), so that I can click the link in one attempt.
Right now I have to click on the blur window(A) to bring it in focus and then the cursor hand appears and then I can click on the links.

Comment: Um, possible for you to give an example or maybe a screen shot of what you are working with. I'm pretty sure the window will have to be in focus but I don't know if I fully understand your question.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't give a screenshot or the code. I can explain the question in detail if there is a specific thing.

Comment: Without the relevant information I cannot assist you any further so I wish you luck in finding a solution.